# Having problem with HTML File with leading encoding characters when sending Email with Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: html, email, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a Jenkins Pipeline script that is trying to send an Email containing an HTML file produced from an NUnit test run.  NUnit places Byte Order Mark (BOM) characters at the beginning of the produced HTML created from an XSLT transform.  When I try to attach this file using the emailext command in my pipeline, the beginning of the email body that is received is similar to the following:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">ï»¿<html>
  <head>
 ......
```

The beginning meta tag is produced by emailext.  Notice the ï»¿ BOM characters follow the meta tag.  Because of this, they are displayed in the e-mail.  How can I send this email attachment so that these BOM characters are stripped out of the HTML file or somehow not displayed in the email?

Here is my pipeline script:

```
emailext to: env.EMAIL_RECIPIENTS,
subject: "${env.MODULE_ID} Test Results",
body: '${FILE,path="TestOutput/ResultDetails.html"}\n\nTest Run Job = ${JOB_URL}',
mimeType: 'text/html'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I basically solved this problem by reading the html into a string, and then stripping off the first 3 characters of the string before setting it to the body of the e-mail.  Not sure if it is the best solution, but it worked for my case.

```
emailContent = readFile(file: "myFile.html").substring(3)   // Strip off the BOM encoding characters.
emailext to: recipients,
         subject: "My Subject",
         body: emailContent,
         mimeType: 'text/html'
```